# Backpack translatable fields dosen't work as expected

Tags: php, laravel-backpack

I'm new working with the Backpack module, I'm trying to make a translatable CRUD following the [documentation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-update#translatable-models). But for a unknown case my preview dosen't works as expected. I mean,it saves correctly in the database the information, in different languages, but when you try to edit in an specific langugae or preview it in a specific language it always shows you the first language, that in this case is English.

Im using laravel 8 with backpack 5 and spatie/laravel-translatable "^4.6".

My BBDD:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('blogposts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id',255);
        $table->text('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->enum('status', ['active', 'deactive'])->default('deactive');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

---

[image]

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\SpatieTranslatable\HasTranslations;

class BlogPost extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasTranslations;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $table = 'blogposts';
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'status'];
    protected $translatable = ['title', 'body'];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];
}
```

As you can see it saves me correctly in the BBDD but when I preview it in a different language it always shos me the english one. Thanks for helping me

Comment: Hello there! Looks like you found a bug in our software. That's definitely not supposed to happen. I've just added an issue in our bug tracker, we expect we'll solve it today or tomorrow the latest. You can follow it here - https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/4396 - thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there Hello There.

Just to let you know that the bug is fixed, merged and tagged and you should be able to get the fixed version with a `composer update backpack/crud`

Cheers